# How can I search for instances of static text in the markup of ASP.NET pages and controls?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, internationalization, markup

I've got an internationalised web application in which all the *text* that eventually gets sent to the browser is generated by code-behind, either by usercontrols that override `Render`, or by code that sets the `Text` of `Label` etc controls.

For example, rather than an `aspx` containing

```
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
```

this application would have instead

```
<h2><asp:Label runat="server" ID="SubTitle" /></h2>
<p><mycontrols:Literal runat="server" ID="Paragraph" /></p>
```

with the actual text only getting supplied at runtime.

I would like to ensure that I haven't inadvertently left any static text in the markup anywhere. However, the ways I can think of all have flaws:

- I can't use a tool that tries to parse the markup as xml, because `*.as?x` markup definitely isn't valid xml
- I can't even use an html parser (such as HtmlAgilityPack), because `*.as?x` markup (remembering this is before it's rendered by ASP.NET) also isn't necessarily valid html (consider how repeater templates can interleave tags)
- Just using Visual Studio Find won't help me find just static text and not, say, CSS class names

Is there any way other than manually checking through every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if it's a a site supporting internationalisation - point one of the many free web site downloaders apps at it - and pull the output onto disk. Run it in French (or language of your choice) then German. Any harcoded text strings will not change. You'll then have to find a WinMerge tool (I think WinMerge can do folders) or write something that can file compare the output. Then PowerGrep to locate the results back in your source.

Comment: Great idea, though as it's an ASP.NET app, you may need to use a test program with some programmability to ensure you download all of the pages in all of their various states.

Comment: Ingenious idea! - in the end I created a dummy language in which all the text was empty, set all the text properties of the data to empty, then tested that every page had no text.